# Want to share multiple remote season(VNC) on Centos7 for same user

Tags: centos7, remote-desktop, tightvnc

I have enabled VNC server in centos7 GUI and able to access remotely. But when I take another remote season, it connects with the existing one. I want to create another season for the same user, so two different people can share same user space without affecting each other. In simple words I want a solution like RDP in windows, where two different person can access one user simultaneously and can work independently(without affecting each other's work ).

Comment: Just start multiple vnc or x servers. Or use X forwarding instead.

Comment: More to the point, use different user accounts.

Comment: @Michael Hampton, I want to user a single user space with multiple session.

Comment: I want to do the same thing on Linux which is mentioned [Here](https://serverfault.com/questions/549297/how-to-enable-the-2-concurrent-1-console-sessions-on-windows-server-2012) for windows.